# how to iterate in cheerio using .each

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, foreach, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape a page to pull in img src into an array. I'm using cheerio library.

Here is what I have:

```
$ = cheerio.load(body);
let flags = [];

$('figure').each(function(i, ele) {
  // get image and country name, website use 'figcaption' under 'figure'
  let imgTag = $(ele).children('img').attr('src');
  let countryName = $(ele).children('figcaption').text().trim();

  // create obj
  let obj = {
    img: imgTag,
    country: countryName
  }

  // add to object
  flags[i] = obj;
  console.log(flags);
});
```

My output looks like this:

```
[ { img:
     'https://cdn.staticaly.com/gh/hjnilsson/country-flags/master/svg/ad.svg',
    country: 'Andorra' } ]
```

I'm not getting any errors in the console. But what I'm looking for is ALL of the img src's. Its currently only grabbing the 1st one.

After researching I saw a github issue where someone tried using an arrow function but based on the cheerio docs you should be using regular functions.

Comment: Since this was webscraping I just decided to use a different site. I was trying to scrape from a github io page so thinking they might have been blocking the script since I believe they are cracking down on that type of activity. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Although the code is a bit awkward without `.map`, it looks OK. Are you sure the HTML is what you think it is?

Answer (score 2):

You really want map:

```
let flags = $('figure').get().map(ele => {
  return {
    img: $(ele).find('img').attr('src'),
    country: $(ele).find('figcaption').text().trim()
  }
})
```

- I'm using js map instead of cheerio map because I think it's simpler.
- The cheerio docs don't use arrow functions because they were written pre-ES6. Feel free to use them.